# Using wget to recursively fetch a directory with --no-parent

Tags: shell, root, wget

I am trying to download all of the files in a directory using:

```
wget -r -N --no-parent -nH -P /media/karunakar --ftp-user=jsjd --ftp-password='hdshd' ftp://ftp.xyz.com/Suppliers/my/ORD20130908
```

but `wget` is fetching files from the parent directory, even though I specified `--no-parent`. I only want the files in `ORD20130908`.

Answer (score 32):

You need to add a trailing slash to indicate the last item in the URL is a directory and not a file:

```
wget -r -N --no-parent -nH -P /media/karunakar --ftp-user=jsjd --ftp-password='hdshd' ftp://ftp.xyz.com/Suppliers/my/ORD20130908
```

↓

```
wget -r -N --no-parent -nH -P /media/karunakar --ftp-user=jsjd --ftp-password='hdshd' ftp://ftp.xyz.com/Suppliers/my/ORD20130908/
```

From the [documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory_002dBased-Limits):

> **Note** that, for HTTP (and HTTPS), the trailing slash is very important to ‘--no-parent’. HTTP has no concept of a “directory”—Wget relies on you to indicate what’s a directory and what isn’t. In ‘http://foo/bar/’, Wget will consider ‘bar’ to be a directory, while in ‘http://foo/bar’ (no trailing slash), ‘bar’ will be considered a filename (so ‘--no-parent’ would be meaningless, as its parent is ‘/’).

Comment: Are you sure you are adding the `/` to the correct place? It seems that you are adding `/` to the prefix path.

Comment: I have test that placing `/` at the end of the URL works, so I take my liberty to edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: Good answer. I wish wget would just error instead of silently ignore an argument.

Answer (score 4):

```
wget -r -N --no-parent -nH -P /media/karunakar --ftp-user=jsjd --ftp-password='hdshd'  -I/ORD20130908 ftp://ftp.xyz.com/Suppliers/my
```

[See wget document for the use of `-I` flag](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#Directory_002dBased-Limits)

Comment: Nice, `-I` is really useful!